# Usuário com múltiplas contas

Tags: suporte

Estava olhando a seguinte pergunta e me deparei com a seguinte situação.

[Query calculando em dobro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52720/4751)

A pergunta foi aberta pelo seguinte usuário [user3163662](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8088/user3163662) e ao ser solicitada mais detalhes por comentário outro usuário [respondeu o comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/107947?noredirect=1) na primeira pessoa.

Achei estranho e perguntei ao usuário se ele era a mesma pessoa e recebi [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/108247?noredirect=1).

Ao meu ver é errado um usuário ter múltiplas contas.

Qual a ação da moderação nesses casos?

*<sup>PS.: Já sinalizei a pergunta</sup>*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ter múltiplas contas não é um problema por si só, embora eu tenha dificuldade de ver alguma vantagem nisso. O que é um problema é essas contas trocarem votos entre si. Isso é absolutamente proibido e sujeito a punição (suspensão).

Existem também muitos casos de gente que cria mais de uma conta sem querer (geralmente pelo menos uma delas não é registrada, e só vale na máquina/browser onde foi criada).

Recomendo que casos assim sejam sempre sinalizados. Os moderadores e gerentes de comunidade irão averiguar e, caso necessário, tomar as devidas providências (que podem ser suspensão, fusão de contas, ou nenhuma ação).